# How can a register have address?

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers, masm32

According to book, register is a place in CPU with small storage space (example 16 bit on 16 bits CPU). So how does CPU register have address? And how are we able to add displacement to it if it not in memory but on CPU?

Example for:

```
mov ax, [bx+1000h]
```

Comment: You are adding displacement to the memory address contained inside BX, you are not moving 1000h bytes from the register BX.

Comment: Normally registers don't have an a memory address, but some do, for example the stack pointer SP in AVR microcontrollers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x86 Registers are only ever addressed by name. The expression `bx+1000h` simply means, "the value in register bx plus 1000h" and the result is interpreted as an address into memory (via the `[...]` notation), not into some register space.

The overall interpretation of the expression is, "Load into ax the 16-bits located 1000h bytes after the address bx points to."

Answer (score 0):

It's done by interpreting the *content* of `bx` as an address and then displacing that with the offset.

So if `bx` is `1000h` then the content of `ax` will be stored at memory location `2000h`